# Improving HBase Data Model

Tags: java, database-design, hbase

I'm starting to work with HBase and I'd like to know if the model I designed is suitable or not, and if it is, how to improve the queries made from the server side.

I'd like to show some User information in an HTML table, showing summarized info for the first time, and when you click, show the detailed info.

This is the model:

**SUMMARIZED_INFO_PER_USER:**

```
Key Sum:1_Field1 Sum:1_Field2 Sum:2_Field1 Sum:2_Field2 ... Id:698745874588 Id:698745874580

 90     Value11       Value12     Value21      Value22   ...       1                2
```

**DETAILED_INFO:**

```
Key  Det:Field1  Det:Field2  Det:Field3  Det:Field4  ....

 1     Value11     Value12     Value13    Value14

 2     Value21     Value22     Value23    Value24
```

Given a specific user(90), I have a column family called Id in the summarized detail table with a reversed timestamp as column name (to benefit from auto descendent order) which has the detail Id (1, 2...), and a second family (Sum) which has the fields I want to show in the fist look.

Moreover, I have a second table in which I store all the detailed information accessed by the detail Id(1, 2 ...) as rows.

My main concern about this model is:

- Is it the best way to access to the last records saved for an user in terms of performance or is it improvable?
- I'm currently taking the entire row for a given user. Then I get the ID family, read the last 10 records, and taking this data by column name as: `[ID_VALUE]_Field1, [ID_VALUE]_Field2, and so on`. Is there any way to do this in HBase, not in Java server? I'm wondering what will happen when a User has 1m records, there will be 1m(Id)+Xm(Sum) columns...
- I'm afraid of joining these two tables in one, because the table will grow alot in columns, but if I keep it in two tables, it won't. We have more items than users, so I think the normal growing should be in rows, not in columns. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not able to get it properly. Why do you have 2 tables? I didn't get your schema.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to improve, according to you, is not necessary to have 2 tables?

Comment: I'm not saying you can't have 2 tables. But if you can achieve your goal by having 1 table it would be better. I was having difficulty in understanding your schema actually.

Comment: @Tariq I've added some more information (last question)